# Search Links on a page

Tags: search, hyperlink

I want to search my link on other pages by passing url address.
After passing the url it should return some boolean value which will define the existence of my link.

Preferred language ASP.net/C#

If it is possible, Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about, sorry. That said, what I do understand is that you want someone to do the work for you, instead of doing it yourself: this is bad. This site is to help you when you have a specific problem, not to do your work.

Comment: I agree with Lo'oris. StackOverflow gives you the "how", not the all done code =).

Answer (score 1):

Get the html of you targeted url, e.g. : using php's `fopen()`, then parse it like a XML document, looking for any `<a>` element having its `href` attribute equal to your own website.

Should be few lines to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTQL COM object to parse the HTML page.  Set a global variable 'link' as your url, then query it by: <a (href = link)>.  If the link is found, isEOF() returns false, else it returns true.

See documentation at: http://htql.net/htql-com-manual.pdf.